# Dividing the first 10 primes into groups whose sum is prime

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, primes

Take the first 10 primes. Can you divide them into $g$ disjoint groups, such that the sum of numbers in each group is prime. In particular can you make this work for every value of $g$ in the range $[2,10]$ ?

Comment: Wow I didn't think this is a textbook problem - I've never seen anything like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one solution. Groups of 1 are implied and not shown

> 2: sum 3...29 = 127
>  
>  3: 2+3 = 5, 5+7+11 = 23, 13+17+19+23+29 = 101
>  
>  4: 5+7+11 = 23, 13+17+19+23+29 = 101
>  
>  5: 2+3 = 5, 5+7+11 = 23, 19+23+29 = 71
>  
>  6: 5+7+11 = 23, 19+23+29 = 71
>  
>  7: 2+3 = 5, 5+7+11 = 23
>  
>  8: 5+7+11 = 23
>  
>  9: 2+3 = 5
>  
>  10: -

Comment: Correct and well done!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I've updated the solution so that all groups are "in order",  i.e. they consist of consecutive primes.

Comment: That is very sexy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly. One of the answers is:

> G10.    2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29
>  G9.      3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29+2
>  G8.      2,3,5,7+11+13,17,19,23,29
>  G7.      3,5,7+11+13,17,19,23,29+2
>  G6      2,3+5+11,7+13+23,17,19,29
>  G5      3+5+11,7+13+23,2+17,19,29
>  G4.      2,11,7+13+23,17+19+29+3+5
>  G3.      3+5+11,7+13+23,2+17+19+29
>  G2.      2,3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23+29

Comment: This is correct.